# Qt QPushbutton Icon above Text

Tags: qt

When I create a QPushButton with an Icon it by default displays the text to the right of the icon. Is there a way to have the text display underneath the icon?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If you're able to, the easiest thing to do is use a [QToolButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtoolbutton.html) instead:

```
QToolButton* button = new QToolButton(this);
button->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonTextUnderIcon);
button->setIcon(myIcon);
button->setText("Sample text");
```

---

If that's not an option you could consider creating your own button widget, possibly derived from QPushButton or QAbstractButton. In this case you'll probably (I haven't tried it myself) want to focus most of your efforts on reimplementing `paintEvent()`.

[Edit: read the comments for alternatives which are probably way simpler than this]

Comment: You can actually add a UI to a QPushButton if you want to.  The automatic sizing can get tricky, but that way you can completely control where an icon and text label go.

Comment: subclassing just for formatting is usually not worth the effort. A lot can be done just by applying styles. And while the documentation on the styles could be better, it works reasonably well and usually as expected.

Comment: This was exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: @jpo38 regarding `[Edit: read the comments for alternatives ...`, could you clarify which comment or solution you are referring to? For example, are you referring to the comment made by **Harald Scheirich Sep 13 '09 at 21:11** in this solution or are you referring to another [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184337/13987321) or another solution's comment?

Comment: @mak: Added this comment 5 years ago, I don't remember...could also be a comment that has been deleted since...

Comment: @jpo38 Thanks for your response. You are right and I forgot that comments can be deleted. I also understand that it has been so long ago.

Answer (score 8):

```
QPushButton {
    padding: -25px 0 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-position: center bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-origin: content;
    background-image: url(":/new/resource/accept.png");
 }
QPushButton:disabled {
    background-image: url(":/new/resource/accept_b.png");
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible with `QPushButton`. In `QPushButton`, the only placement options (LayoutDirection) are `LeftToRight`, `RightToLeft` and `Auto`. But you can use `QToolButton` instead.

Use Qt Creator, switch to *Design* pane, add a `QToolButton` and in the right side bottom pane, you will see an option '`textFormat`', in that select `ToolButtonTextUnderIcon`.

**Update:** The `textFormat` option has been changed to `toolButtonStyle` in recent versions of Qt Creator (4.7.0).

Comment: In my qtcreator it is called "toolButtonStyle".

Comment: that's for QToolButton, the OP asks about QPushButton

Comment: @LennartRolland Thanks I updated my answer to reflect the new change.

Comment: @cz Updated the answer to mention that it is not possible with `QPushButton`