# what is the good approach to programming a custom button in Qt?

Tags: qt

I would like to make a custom button that acts like a `QPushButton` (I specifically need the `clicked` signal and the whole checkable machinery `setChecked(True)`...).

I want my button to have an icon on the right hand side, vertically centered. And on the left hand side I would like to have 2 labels.

My first naïve attempt was to subclass `QAbstractButton`, and insert my widget in it like I would with a regular `QWidget` (giving it a layout, adding my subwidgets in it...). That did not work at all.

Do I need to start from a basic `QWidget` and implement myself the entire button machinery, or is there a better way that I am missing?

This is roughly the result I would like to achieve (first one is enabled and not checked, second one is checked, third one is disabled) :

[image]

Comment: Why not subclass QPushButton? Also, have you looked at what you can do with Qt Style Sheets?

Comment: This might help to start on something : https://stackoverflow.com/q/44091339/6165833 (and this https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184337/6165833)

Comment: I'm ok with the stylesheets. What I do not understand is how to subclass a `QPushButton` while completly changing the content of the inside layout. I am under the impression that QPushButtons are limited to one piece of text and one icon.

Comment: @ymoreau I have seen other exemples of subclassing QAbstractPushButton and override paintEvent, but again it seems limited to tweaking the way the one pixmap is drawn and the one text is printed. I haven't been able to find an example that creates a button with multiples labels (with each a different stylesheet), multiples images...

Comment: A QPushButton itself is a widget, so you can add some child labels and use a QGridLayout to arrange them instead of using button's own text and icon.

Comment: I will try again, then. Yesterday I tried that using a QAbstractButton, but nothing was displayed

Comment: Ok I confirm that it works with a QPushButton, but that the exact same code does not work with a QAbstractButton (which is a QWidget too). Thanks for the solution. There is something that I don't understand about QAbstractButton.

Comment: May be, the "Abstract" in `QAbstractButton`? ;-)