# Implementing Qpushbutton in Qt and cpp

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5, qpushbutton

I want to implement a Qpushbutton like in the image below. I don't want it to be done in widget.ui but rather code it. How can I do it in stylesheet?

```
QPushButton *settings=new QpushButton("Settings", this);
QString css= QString("qproperty-icon:url(:/settings.bmp;");
settings->setStyleSheet(css);
```

And i want the image on top of the text as below-
[Button image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8isrS.jpg)

Tried changing stylesheet options but not successful.

Comment: If it doesn't have to be a `QPushButton`, you could use `QToolButton`'s style as demonstrated here: [Qt QPushbutton Icon above Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418578/qt-qpushbutton-icon-above-text)